# Howto change the label text color of a LineChartDataset? Se below my sample text "Linechart text"

Tags: c#, .net, blazorise

how it is possible to change the label text color in a Blazorise LineChartDataset?

```
    linecharts[0] = new LineChartDataset<decimal>() 
    {                
      Label = "Linechart text ", //<== This text should change color
      Data = list[0],
      BackgroundColor = backColorE,
      BorderColor = borColorE,
      CubicInterpolationMode = "monotone",
    };
```

At the moment it is gray and i have no idea why.

many thanks for your help
elu